# Discord js Random image embed but outside embed

Tags: discord, bots

So I'm trying to make a script that runs a random image when someone uses `!inspire` command I have the code working but the embed fires the random images outside of the embed?

```
bot.on("messageCreate", message => {
const channel1 = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === '-bot-chat')
    if (message.content.startsWith (prefix,'inspire')) {
        message.delete(1000);
        const idx = (len) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (len));
        const files = fs.readdirSync('/images/'); 
        const myImage = files[idx(files.length)];
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Just a test")
        channel1.send({ embeds: [embed], files: [`/images/${myImage}`] });
    }
})
```

[Here what it's doing now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HihJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `files` attribute in the `channel1.send()` function. That makes the image outside the embed.

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor

The `.setImage()` attribute makes the image wrapped INSIDE the embed. That's how it works :)